# Cambiar imagen usando onclick en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, menu

Consulta, estoy haciendo un burger menu con JavaScript. Pude lograr que al clickear en el icono burger.svg se despliegue el menu y el icono cambie a close.svg (X), pero cuando aprieto en la X, si bien el menu vuelve a cerrarse, queda la X y no vuelve a aparecer el icono de burger.

```js
function cambiarClaseSrc(){
    let siteNav = document.getElementById ('site-nav');
        siteNav.classList.toggle('site-nav-open');
    let openBurger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
        if (openBurger.src.match == "close") {
            openBurger.src = "./asset/burger.svg";
        } else {
            openBurger.src = "./asset/close.svg";
    } 
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle" onclick="cambiarClaseSrc()">
    <img id="hamburger" class="hamburger" src="./asset/burger.svg" alt="Icono menu 
    hamburguesa/close">
 </div>
```

En que le estoy errando?

---

Bien calamari, así el icono burger se vé, pero no cambia por close, eso si, si clickeo teniendo el inpeccionador abierto se veo el cambio de codigo, pero no en la imagen de la pagina, en que le estoy errando?
**HTML**

```
<header>        
    <div class="container-logo">
        <img class="gifos-logo" src="./asset/logo-mobile.svg" alt="Logo Gifos">  
    </div>
    <nav id="site-nav" class="site-nav">   
        <ul>         
            <li><a href="index-dark.html">Modo Nocturno</a></li>
            <div class="separator-line"></div>
            <li><a href="favorites.html">Favoritos</a></li>
            <div class="separator-line"></div>
            <li><a href="mis-gifos.html">Mis Gifos</a></li>
            <div class="separator-line"></div>
            <a class="btn-more" href="./mis-gifos.html"><img src="./asset/button-crear-gifo.svg" alt="Icono boton mas"></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle" onclick="cambiarClaseSrc()">   
        <img id="burger" class="burger" src="./asset/burger.svg" alt="Icono menu  hamburguesa/close"> 
    </div>            
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-toggle{
    .close {
        background-image: url('./asset/close.svg');
    }
    .burger{
        background-image: url('./asset/burger.svg');
    }   
}
```

**JS**

```
function cambiarClaseSrc() {
menu = document.getElementById("menu-toggle");
menu.classList.toggle("burger");
menu.classList.toggle("close");
```

}

Answer (score 2):

La condición está mál escrita:

```
if (openBurger.src.match == "close") {
```

debería ser algo como

```
if (openBurger.src.contains("close")) {
```

Comment: Lo revisé y funcionó! estaba por ahí el tema GRACIAS PABLO!

Answer (score 1):

¿No puedes cargar la imagen por CSS y usar `toogleList.toogle` para cambiar las imágenes ?

No sé si sería lo más correcto pero sería algo así:

```js
function cambiar() {
  menu = document.getElementById("menu")
  menu.classList.toggle("burger")
  menu.classList.toggle("close")
}
```

```css
.close {
  background-image: url('imagen1.jpg')
}
.burger {
  background-image: url('imagen2.jpg')
}
```

```html
<span id="menu" class="burger" onClick="cambiar()"> </span>
```

Adaptándolo a tu código quedaría así; tendrías que crear dos clases en CSS con las URLs de las imágenes, asignar en el HTML la clase que tenga la imagen 'burger.svg' y luego con Javascript se cambian las clases al hacer click.

Si tienes cualquier duda postea tu nuevo código y lo miramos.

```js
function cambiarClaseSrc() {
  menu = document.getElementById("menu-toggle")
  menu.classList.toggle("hamburger")
  menu.classList.toggle("close")
}
```

```css
.close {
  background-image: url('./asset/close.svg');
}
.hamburger{
  background-image: url('./asset/burger.svg');
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle" onclick="cambiarClaseSrc()"></div>
```

Comment: Hola calamari, gracias por responder, lo adapte a mi codigo pero no pude lograr que funcione. No se si por error mio o por el codigo. Estoy cursando JS, y a lo mejor no lo adapte bien, te consulto como lo harias en el codigo posteado en la pregunta inicial?

Comment: @FabricioHang He editado la respuesta adaptando el código a la respuesta inicial. Si te sigue sin funcionar me comentas y lo miramos.

Comment: oka en algo le estoy errando reviso de nuevo. Mil Gracias!!

Comment: @FabricioHang Perdona que no lo haya puesto ante pero te dejo un Codepen para que puedas probarlo: https://codepen.io/Calamari_love/pen/MWbZoEw